# How to sign and verify data with ethereumjs-utils?

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs, ethereumjs, keccak

In my contract I'm verifying if some data was correctly signed by the owner. It looks like this:

```
require(
    owner() ==
        ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, aCustomId)), v, r, s),
        "owner should sign aCustomId"
    );
```

Which means i should be retrieving v, r, s from a backend, which I currently do like this:

```
import * as ethUtil from 'ethereumjs-util';

const hash = soliditySha3(
  'myContractAddress',
  '11111',
);
const signature = ethUtil.ecsign(
    ethUtil.toBuffer(hash),
    wallet.getPrivateKey(),
);

return {
      r: ethUtil.bufferToHex(signature.r),
      s: ethUtil.bufferToHex(signature.s),
      v: signature.v,
      aCustomId: 11111,
};
// return the v, r, s
```

however, it seems like it's not correct as I keep getting "owner should sign aCustomId".

How can i create the correct hash so my v,r,s parameters are correct for recovering later ?

I'm using solidity version 0.6.12

The contract is called something like this:

```
myContract.methods
    .someMethod(
        11111,
        vValueAsInt,
        "sValue",
        "rValue",
    )
    .send({ from: account }, function(
        error: any,
        transactionHash: any
    ) {
        console.log(transactionHash);
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Which version of solidity are you using ? Also please provide the js code which calls the contract function.

Comment: Solidity is version 0.6.12, added js code in the original post

Comment: Where is the code returning the r,s,v parameters ?

Comment: ah, that was on the backend, i also added that part now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code with web3js 1.3.0, ethereumjs-utils 5.2.5 and solidity 0.6.12 :

### Javascript part

```
//hash the data
const hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(
myContractAddress,
aCustomId,
);
//prefix the hash 
const prefixedHash = ethUtil.hashPersonalMessage(ethUtil.toBuffer(hash));

//get the ECDSA signature and its r,s,v parameters
const privateKey = new Buffer(myPrivateKey, "hex")
const signature = ethUtil.ecsign(prefixedHash, privateKey);
r = ethUtil.bufferToHex(signature.r),
s = ethUtil.bufferToHex(signature.s),
v = signature.v;

//call the contract method
myContract.methods.verifySig(accountAddress, aCustomId, r, s, v) 
.send({ from: accountAddress }).on('receipt', function(receipt){
  console.log(receipt);
})
```

Note that we use `hashPersonalMessage` in addition to `soliditySha3` in order to add a prefix to the data before signing it. This prefix is : `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32"`. It's a security standard which prevents attacks such as a malicious attempt to make a user sign a transaction while making him believe that he is signing a message.

### Smart contract

```
function verifySig(address owner, uint256 aCustomId, bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) public view {
bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address(this), aCustomId));
bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, hash));
require(ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s) == owner);
}
```

The two important things here are :

- To get the address of the contract we use `address(this)` (and not `this`).
- We do the same operations that we did in the backend : first we hash the data, and then we compute the prefixed hash.