# How to transfer the transaction gas to the user

Tags: web3js, blockchain, erc-20, nft

I´m developing a NFT game with ER20 token. When the player plays the game it earns token. After some time, the player can withdraw the amount of tokens that are inside the game and send to your metamask wallet.

To do that, my backend signs the transaction with the private key of the owner and send tokens to the player (i´m paying the gas because i´m doing this transaction).

But I want to transfer the gas fees to the player. How can I do this strategy?

There are a lot of NFT games that implements this strategy right now, but I don´t know how to use web3 and solidity to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer the gas fees to the player"? Can the users withdraw without paying fees? Or do you want each user to pay for withdrawing the tokens? Or something else completely.

Comment: @Ismael I want that when user withdraw tokens they should pay the gas fee.

Comment: You could sign a message in the backend and let the user send the message to the contract. The contract could validate the signature and process the request.

Comment: @Ismael do you have a example how to do this?

Comment: If you search you'll find several examples how to sign a message https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90625/how-to-sign-and-verify-data-with-ethereumjs-utils. You should also read about EIP-712 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712.